# What does a reference inside a div tag without an attribute do?

Tags: html, css, attributes

I would like to start using Attribute Selectors in my css. I am seeing div tags that contain a reference WITHOUT any attribute statement like:

```
<div class="container" data-footer>
```

All my searches (for the last hour) to find out how "data-footer" can be listed without the use of an attribute= (e.g., id= or class= or etc.) have resulted in no information. Dozens of SO and Google links without a single example of a reference inside a div tag without the use of an attribute. Because I do not know what this is (or what to call it) I'm probably not searching with the right keywords. Is this a short-form way to pass an id or ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML data-* Attribute](https://www.dofactory.com/html/attributes/data)

Comment: I will have to dig deeper but your reference still shows an attribution (e.g., data-id="205"). I have not seen (yet) any example of a reference just floating without an attribute. I will keep reading the link.

Comment: @Emre Every example in the recommended link shows an exact use of the attribute (e.g., data-registration-number="40039") so I am not seeing how this answers what a reference without an attribute does/means. The link you provided states "An <div> element can have any number of data-* attributes, each with their own name." In my example in my OP, wouldn't the data-footer have to equal something to follow the format shown in your recommended link?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you in the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data- attributes without a value can be used as Boolean. For example:

```
if(div.hasAttribute('data-footer')) {
   // then do something
}
```

In css you can access it like:

```
div[data-footer] {

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Odd that I did not find a single reference to this anywhere in my searches. This information will help me refine my search so I can learn more about this. Again, thank you!